# AgileCRM : Add Current day in compaing email

Tags: agile-crm

I am developing marketing campaign , I want to insert the day name in campaign. I Try to add date using custom field but it is not possible . Please suggest any solution

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any direct way to get current day in AgileCRM campaigns. However I can suggest using [JSONIO](https://github.com/agilecrm/agile-crm-json-io-node) node with URL http://www.convert-unix-time.com/api?date=now&timezone=vienna to get current date and time w.r.t timezone. You can use {{localDate}} as merge field wherever you need after JSONIO node.